# Alibiaktion vs. Tokenismus (Difference/Unterschied)

Tags: difference, vocabulary

Ich weiß und verstehe was "Tokenismus" bedeutet. Dies Wort stammt vom englischen Wort "Token(ism)". Es ist gut beschrieben in Englisch-Wörterbüchern:

> Tokenism: The practice of making only a perfunctory or symbolic effort to do a
>   particular thing, especially by recruiting a small number of people
>   from under-represented groups in order to give the appearance of
>   sexual or racial equality within a workforce.

Quelle: Oxford Dictionary

Ich habe das Wort "Alibiaktion" in dem folgenden Satz gelesen aber ich verstehe nicht, was es genau bedeutet und den Unterschied zwischen "Alibiaktion" und "Tokenismus"

> Um Kritik an diskriminierenden und ausgrenzenden Verhältnissen
>   abzuwenden oder entsprechenden Antidiskriminierungsgesetzen zu
>   genügen, wird Tokenismus auch als Alibiaktion missbraucht.

Quelle: Ein Wikipedia-Artikel über das Thema "Tokenismus", [Link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenismus)

Ich konnte das Wort in Wörterbüchern nicht finden. Dict.cc übersetzt es als "tokenism" ins Englische. Aber das reicht leider nicht, den Unterschied zu bezeichnen.

Könnt Ihr bitte erklären, was der Unterschied ist?

Comment: *„Tokenismus“ kann gegenwärtig nicht als im Deutschen üblich gebrauchtes Wort angesehen werden.* Quelle: der oben genannte Artikel. Dem stimme ich zu. Weswegen ich auch nicht verstehe, warum der Artikel nicht gleich *Tokenism* genannt wurde, um den angelsächsischen Begriffsbezug zu erhalten. Bei *Computer* machen sie es doch auch so. Und umgekehrt benennen die en-wpler ihren *Weltschmerz*-Artikel auch nicht *world weariness*.

Comment: @Janka: erklär nur noch, dass eine *Alibiaktion* in diesem Satz nix mit Tokenism zu tun hat, dann hast du eine Antwort und musst nicht auf einem Kommentar sitzen bleiben.

Comment: Da scheint mir eher eine technische Begriffsklärung in Richtung von Psychologie/Soziologie o. ä. gefragt zu sein, als sprachliche Unterstützung. Ich betrachte das als off-topic.

Comment: @Janka: Die Wikipedia ist ein kollaboratives Produkt von tausenden Autoren. Dass sich da alle gleichmäßig an ein einheitliches Vorgehen halten ist eher unwahrscheinlich.

Comment: So wie ich Wikipedia verstehe ist jeder Tokenismus eine Alibiaktion. Zu sagen, Tokenismus würde als Alibiaktion missbraucht, ist demnach Quatsch.

Comment: Auch wenn's tausende Autoren sind, ohne Regel ist es nicht. Der entscheidende Punkt ist, dass der Artikel selbst dem Lemma widerspricht. Soviel Sorgfalt sollte jeder Schreiberling aufbringen, den Widerspruch zu erkennen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tokenismus ist eine Alibiaktion, aber **nicht jede Alibiaktion ist ein Tokenismus**.

Beispielsweise könnte eine Firma im Werbespot ihre antirassistische Haltung betonen, aber trotzdem Menschen aufgrund ihrer Herkunft bei der Bewerbung diskriminieren. Dann wäre der Werbespot eine Alibiaktion, aber kein Tokenismus.

Weiterhin gibt es **Alibiaktionen auch jenseits von diskriminierenden Verhaltensweisen**.

Beispielsweise zitiert [dieser Tagesspiegel-Artikel](https://m.tagesspiegel.de/politik/die-seeblockade-der-nato-ist-eine-alibiaktion/3986558.html) von 2011 einen Politiker: Dieser nennt eine NATO-Seeblockade zur Verhinderung von Waffenschmuggel eine Alibiaktion, da kaum Waffenschmuggel auf dem Seeweg stattfindet.